# Add new Block in the Controller and set this on the first position

Tags: magento, position, block

I add a new Block in my Controller, this is working.

```
$this->loadLayout();
$cmsBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cms_block_fail');
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($cmsBlock);
$this->renderLayout();
```

In the Layout.xml I set in the "content" structurblock an other contentblock.

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="contactus/form" name="contact_us" template="contactus/contactus.phtml"/> 
</reference>
```

I want the CMS block before the `contact_us` block. In the `Layout.xml` I can use the parameters before and after. If I write `after="-"` the block will be set on the last position of the structure block "content", that's right? This is not working. How can I set this parameter with `php` in the Controller? Or other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->insert($cmsBlock,'contact_us');` should cause the `$cmsBlock` to be `array_splice()`ed into the `content` block's `_sortedChildren()` array ahead of the `contact_us` block.

The logic is a bit abstruse but you can find more information about how this works in [`Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::insert()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php#L625) - note that `append($block)` is essentially an alias for `insert($block,'',true)`.